# ios shortcut help regarding javascript back

Tags: javascript, io, shortcut

I've been browsing stackoverflow and I cant find a solution to what I'm trying to do

Simply put, i want to create a shortcut that i can pair with iOS Backtap feature which when I backtap my Iphone, it will run the shortcut to go back to my previous visited web page(i.e. `history.back()`)

I understand the functions but i do not know how to put it all together.

I've tried `function(goBack)`
and various forms of `javascript:history.back()`

Comment: nvm figured it out

Comment: Please add more context to this question, because I have no idea why you are using js or where?